# Unix sort out of memory

Tags: sort

I'm sorting a 25 GB file containing 200M lines on Fedora 18 using:

sort -S 10G -T /bigdisk bigfile

and I am getting process killed due to no memory. The process isn't maxing out my RAM before death (12 GB free) and disk space is ok.

Any suggestions as to the cause appreciated. I'm sure sort can manage this due to its partitioning and merge.

More info from dmesg

```
[87278.935572] Out of memory: Kill process 1971 (sort) score 258 or sacrifice child
[87278.935574] Killed process 1971 (sort) total-vm:4512168kB, anon-rss:4237040kB, file-rss:584kB
```

Comment: Does the system have any per process or per user RAM limits? (check with limit or ulimit)

Comment: nope, Firefox and eclipse manage to eat it all :)

Comment: Does it really get killed? You may connect with strace shortly before the crash and have a look at what's really happening.

Comment: Is this a 32 or 64 bit kernel?

Comment: 64 bit kernel. it gets killed, output is via dmesg sigalling killed for memory as opposed to a segfault or something

Comment: feedback as to the close votes?

Comment: what is the output of sysctl vm.overcommit_memory

Comment: vm.overcommit_memory = 0

Comment: Also, I am swap off. 16GB should be enough for anyone and performance is key. Currently i've switched to split/sort -m and a parallel makefile to try and make progress.

Comment: Are all lines the same length? Then I would propose a sort-in-place, i.e. mmap the file and quicksort it.

Comment: It gets OOMkilled and tweaking overcommit will NOT make it work! It IS taking all of your memory before killing (or another process does), otherwise, the OOMkiller wouldn't launch. I think `-S 10G` (i.e. sort's *main memory buffer*) is far too much, don't do this.

Comment: Does `ulimit` return anything?

Comment: @jippie ulimit says "unlimited"

Comment: I had the same problem when I used `/run/shm` as my `/bigdisk` for storing sorts temp files. It seems the kernel considers the ram disk in `/run/shm` as more important, so when sort was writing to it and memory ran out, the kernel killed sort. Using a sluggish VM hard disk instead solved it.

Comment: @AidenBell - Did you ever get your problem sorted out? It's 10 years later and I'm trying to sort a ~300 GB file on an AWS m5.4xlarge (16 proc, 64 GB RAM). We keep getting killed by the OOM and it looks like swap space is exhausted. This machine is launched for the purpose of doing this sort, so there's literally nothing else running.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `-S 10G`, it is far too much (and probably not doing what you think). OOMkiller launching **does** mean your system is using all of it's memory.

According to the [algorithm used](http://vkundeti.blogspot.fr/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html) by `sort`, *it will use memory according to what is available*: half of the biggest number between TotalMem/8 and AvailableMem.

So, for example, if you have 4 GB of available mem (out of 8 GB), `sort` will use 2GB of RAM. It should also create many 2 GB files in /bigdisk and finally merge-sort them.

Comment: To be fair, sort is killed off if I use -S or not. Both top and /proc/meminfo report I have free memory on death. The machine has 16G of ram and only 3 is actually in use when the sort process is launched. Manually using split, sort on the parts and them sort -m worked with no memory issues.

Comment: @AidenBell I just thought of something: are you using a 32 bit version of `sort`? Check with `file $(which sort)`.

Comment: nope. 64-bit. I'm beginning to think it might be an actual *gasp* bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Making an answer from my comment:

I had the same problem when I used `/run/shm` as my `/bigdisk` for storing `sort` temp files. `/run/shm` is a ram disk, so when sort needed to cache partial results on disk (which it does when memory is almost full), memory ran out. The kernel killed `sort`, as it was the process using the most memory.

Using a location stored on a physical disk instead of the ram disk solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting [`vm.overcommit_memory = 1`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt?id=b0af9cd9aab60ceb17d3ebabb9fdf4ff0a99cf50#n533): «…

> When this flag is 1, the kernel pretends there is always enough
>   memory until it actually runs out.

…»

And *do* use swap.

Comment: The OOM killer is only triggered when "it actually runs out" of memory. So this settings won't solve anything. It might have if the *Out of mem* message had come from `sort` and **not** from the kernel.

Comment: RTFM: „… The OOM killer can be completely disabled with the following command. This is not recommended for production environments, because if an out-of-memory condition does present itself, there could be unexpected behavior depending on the available system resources and configuration. … anything from a kernel panic to a hang depending on the resources available to the kernel at the time of the OOM condition.

sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
echo "vm.overcommit_memory=2" >> /etc/sysctl.conf …” ­— http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of your comment. Disabling OOM-killer will **not** solve the problem, which is: `sort` uses/needs too much memory. With `overcommit_memory=2`, `sort` will just fail to `malloc()` and will very probably fail to sort, then.

Comment: mine answer wasn't =2. It was a cite showing that settings of this option has direct relation to OOM-killing. If you want to know the subject better, well, okay, that would suit your purpose (hopefully): http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/