# direct GNU sort to use much memory and many cores

Tags: sort, gnu

I have a fairly large text file (19Gb, half a billion lines) and a fairly large server on which to sort it (16 cores, 64Gb memory) running Ubuntu 12.04.

What is the best way to use the command line `sort` utility (it's from GNU core utilities) to quickly sort this file?

I believe I can use `--parallel 15` (leaving one core free), <del>can use something like `-T /run/shm/sortTmp` to keep temp files on a ram disk (so it's fast)</del><sup>1</sup>, can use `-S 50G` to utilise available memory and can tweak `--batch-size=15` to reduce the use of temp files (here I'm not sure what a good value would be..).

Are there other options to consider? What is a good choice for `--batch-size`? Are there other things I should be considering?

There is nothing else that needs to be running on the machine while I'm doing the sort, so I can use all it's resources.

<sup>1</sup> `-S` in combination with the ram disk for temp files is a bad idea! The kernel will likely kill `sort` when it writes to the ram disk and memory is almost full (see [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/unix-sort-out-of-memory#comment331759_68168))

Answer (score 1):

Nobody's answering, so this is what I did:

```
sort -T /mnt/tmp --parallel=14 -S 50G myBigFile.txt
```

I didn't use `--batch-size` as I wasn't sure what would be a good value and presumably `sort` is clever about it anyway.

`/mnt` is mounted on a big ephemeral disk (the machine is a VM in the cloud). If `/tmp` is on a disk with plenty of space, you could leave out `-T`. If you've got a very fast disk with enough space, use that.

If I remember correctly, it needs about the same space again as the size of the file being sorted - basically it divides the file into two or more chunks which it can each sort in memory, stores them sorted in the temp disk, then does a merge sort to produce the final output.